# View server-side code in a DotNetNuke-7 module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am using DotNetNuke version 7.0. I develop DNN modules on my local computer with Visual Studio. After building a module, I upload it to the server by logging in as a master user and installing an extension (I take the install-file, but I also tried the source-file). This all works very well.  Unfortunately I can't see my server-side code on the server after uploading and installing a module. The file is not displayed when I open Visual Studio on the server. Everything that is executed at the client-side is displayed. However, the code behind it is missing on the server. However, the module works perfectly. So the server-side code must be somewhere. But I can't find it.

How do I access the code behind when I'm on the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by myself. To see the complete code of a module you have to create the module in the folder "DesktopModules". Then you have to install the extension in the web interface of DotNetNuke. For this you should use the install.zip and not the source.zip. Then, if you want to edit the module, you can open the solution of the module. My mistake was that I opened the whole DotNetNuke project, which of course was wrong. If you only open the solution of the module, all codes are correctly placed and visible. This makes it very easy to edit the module. You change the code as you like and then rebuild the project. With this action the DotNetNuke Projekt takes over all changes of the module and no new installation is necessary. Debugging is also possible. For this you only have to press Start and set a debug point accordingly.

Thanks anyway for the help of all people involved in this question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems module compiled version is installed on your server.Did you tried removing/uninstalling the extension and reinstalling (source zip)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But then the file View.ascx.designer.cs is always outside the View.ascx file. This leads to the fact that attributes are not found. How can I make the file View.ascx.designer.cs a child element of the file View.ascx.cs?

Comment: I have opened a new question which deals with the fact that the file View.ascx.designer.cs is wrongly positioned in the solution explorer. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921116/the-file-designer-cs-is-incorrectly-nested-in-the-solution-explorer-and-cannot-b