# The file designer.cs is incorrectly nested in the Solution Explorer and cannot be moved

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, code-behind

I am using DotNetNuke 9.0.01. Here I created a module in Visual Studio and installed it in the DNN extensions. I didn't use the installation file but the one with the source code. Unfortunately now the file View.ascx.designer.cs is not below the View.ascx. It is outside the code-behind.

This also leads to the problem that intellisense doesn't know the attributes and therefore I can't use them. This in turn leads to the fact that I cannot compile. So it's not just a display problem.

I have tried to exclude the files from the project and include them again. But that doesn't work. I have also tried to modify the .csproj file. But that doesn't work either. I have also looked up at the properties but didn't find a solution.

I expected the datastructure to be like that:

```
>View.ascx
>>View.ascx.cs
>>View.ascx.designer.cs
```

But it is like that:

```
>View.ascx
>>View.ascx.cs
>View.ascx.designer.cs
```

Comment: Maybe the [File Nesting add-in](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting) for Visual Studio is helpful to you?

Comment: Thank you Uwe Keim. But what should I do with it? I installed it now. Visual Studio restarted. And set all options to 'true'. But unfortunately without success. designer.cs is still wrongly positioned and drag and drop doesn't work. When dragging and dropping I get the following error message: 'Cannot move 'View.ascx.designer.cs'. The destination folder is the same as the source folder.'

Comment: Usually, when I have such wrong nestings, I manually edit the CSPROJ file directly in an external text editor. I examine correct nestings and re-build the wrong nesting by the same pattern I saw at the correct nesting.

Comment: Copy the two cs files to a temporary location.  Then open the solution explorer and delete the View file(s).  Next go into the project folder and make sure the View files are deleted in main folder.  The View obj and dll files should also get removed in the obj folder and the bin folder.  Now copy the two cs files back to the main folder.  From Solution explorer Second Row (The project) Right click and Add Existing Item : Browse in project folder for the select the form (not designer) the designer should automatically get added.

Comment: @jdweng now I have managed that the file View.ascx.cs is also outside. So the thing has got worse XD

Comment: @Uwe Keim in my .csproj file it looks like this: 
`<Compile Include="View.ascx.cs"><DependentUpon>View.ascx</DependentUpon>
<SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="View.ascx.designer.cs">
<DependentUpon>View.ascx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
`
what would you change?

Comment: Just compare with an entry that is correctly nested.

Comment: There is no entry that is correctly nested.

Comment: Create a new windows form project.  Then SaveAll. Then open new .proj file with current .proj file.  You can edit .proj file so they look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by myself. So basically I have to say that I use DotNetNuke (DNN) 9.0.01 as I already wrote in my question. For this I created a new module via Visual Studio and then installed this module in the DotNetNuke web interface. It is important to use the Install.zip and not the source.zip. Furthermore the location of the module is very important. This must be located in the folder "DesktopModules". Already when creating the module! If you want to edit the module now, you have to open in Visual Studio the solution of the module and not the whole DotNetNuke project.  That was my mistake. If you open the solution of the module, all files are nested correctly. If you now make changes to the module and rebuild the module, all changes in the entire DotNetNuke project will be applied.

Thanks anyway to everyone who tried to help me.